# Load data before component inialization - angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

My `App.component` which calls a init method in my `user service`.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.init(true).then(data => {
        console.log("OnInit Called")
    })     
}
```

`User.service` returns a `promise` which in turn calls the `account.init`

```
init = (isRegistered) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        this.account.init(isRegistered).then(data => {
            //some data inialization
            console.log("OnInit Called User Service")            
        });          
    });   
}
```

`Account.service` returns a promise which calls several services using `Observable`.forkJoin

```
init = ((userType: boolean) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         Observable.forkJoin([
             this.m1,
             this.m2]).subscribe(data => {
                 //persist those return data   
             });           
    });
}
```

1. Why are both console.log statements never gets executed?
2. Why does it not prevent the component inialization before the Observable.forkJoin complets its service calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (and 2.) call to `resolve(...)` missing

```
init = (isRegistered) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        this.account.init(isRegistered).then(data => {
            //some data inialization
            console.log("OnInit Called User Service")            
            resolve(/*someValue */); // <<<== missing
            // or reject(/* someValue */);
        });          
    });   
}
```

2. Why do you expect it to block anything? `ngOnInit()` can't be blocked. You can for example use `*ngIf` to not show anything before the data is not yet available. 
   You can also use a router guard to prevent component creation before data is available. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard
   But there is no way to block execution in any way in JS.

Comment: you are as always right, but actually you can make a synchronous server call, so it is possible to block the execution :) It's pointless, but it is possible

Comment: Ok, I assumed that was deprecated, but it's still debatable if this really blocks execution. It's just occupying the UI thread - a for loop could do the same, but as you said - quite pointless anyway :D

Comment: :) for loop can block the execution but it won't ever be able to receive a result of async call because it will be pushed to the event queue. The only way to block the execution until async response is received would be either a ES6 generator or async/await... Still pointless :D

Comment: Also generators and `async/await` don't block, they are only syntactic sugar for `.then( ...)`, the behavior is the same, just the code can be written in a nicer way.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely have to resolve the Promise first.

```
init = (isRegistered) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        this.account.init(isRegistered).then(data => {
            // some data initialization
            if (data) {
                resolve(...);
            } else {
                reject(...);
            }
            console.log("OnInit Called User Service")            
        });          
    });   
}
```

It's hard to tell what's the problem because we don't know what `this.m1` and `this.m2` are.

Don't get surprised when using `forkJoin()`. This operator `forkJoin()` doesn't emit any value if one of its source Observables fail or doesn't emit any value and complete prematurely.